# Drywall skim coat has bubbles. How to fix?

Tags: painting, patch

I primed my walls yesterday and noticed that there are tiny holes (1mm diam) from bubbles in the skim coat. I primed it anyway thinking that the primer will fill the holes. 
[image: primed skim coated wall with bubbles holes]

What's the best way to hide the bubbles? 
Caulk? Speckle? More mud? 
Note: I want to paint very soon and want the easiest solution.

Answer (score 3):

Could be that your mud wasn't mixed well and had settled a bit, leaving excess water on top. A firmer application or a more thorough mix might've helped prevent bubbles.

At any rate, just skim it again, and press firmly using the edge of the blade. If you do it right it won't even need sanding (or maybe just a wipe).

Comment: The sheen is from the white primer perhaps? Can I use something else besides mud? Or is mud the right consistency to fill those little holes?

Comment: Yeah, I realized I had misread. Edited. Drywall mud will fill those just fine. It's not an uncommon phenomenon.

Comment: Use "topping" mud rather than "joint compound", it works better for skim-coat applications. IMO it goes on smoother and is less likely to bubble.

Comment: True, but I wouldn't buy anything new just for this minor fix.